# Guarantees on memory ordering and proper programming practice

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, intel, amd-processor

With respect to the ordering I describe below I have some related questions.

1. Given these ordering guarantees I don't need explicit fences in many places. However, how can I express the "fence" to the compiler, in particular GCC?  That is, the guarantee of program order only applies so long as the optimizer doesn't reorder my program.
2. Are there common/popular new chips in use that have general purpose cores that do not offer such guarantees?
3. I'm a bit confused in C++0x with its idea of interleaving. Must I use the "atomic" class to make use of these guarantees, or is there some other aspect in the draft which also provides a way to make use of these guarantees?

---

*Memory Ordering*

Both Intel and AMD, at least with x86_64, guarantee that memory loads are sequential with respect to the store operations done on a single processor.  That is, if some processor executes these stores:

1. Store A <- 1
2. Store B <- 2
3. Store C <- 3

The moment some other processor sees C(3) it is guaranteed to also see the previous stores A(1) and B(2). Now, the visibility between processors may be interleaved, but the store order from any given processor will also be sequential.

They also have transitive guarantees when Processor 0 reads a value stored by Processor 1, then writes a value, that Processor 2 reading the new value must also see that value from Processor 1.

*Ignore the special cases dealing with IO and special devices. I'm interested only in the general memory guarantees: my ordering here is just the bit I'm most interested in as it has the most significance for concurrent algorithms.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mastery of these kinds of operations is essential for building SMP operating systems and for communicating with certain kinds of hardware. The Linux kernel documentation provides an excellent overview of the subject along with the specific solutions used by the kernel. I highly recommend taking a look at their [memory-barriers.txt](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt) file.

Answer (score 0):

For the strongest guarantees that your stores and loads will be executed in *precisely* the required order, you may need to resort to `asm` blocks in your code and write out your `mov` instructions explicitly.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is neither necessary nor sufficient. Unless appropriate barrier instructions are used as well, a CPU core will be free to reorder instructions at runtime if it thinks it can get away with it. These barriers are also available as higher-level primitives, negating the need to resort to assembly.

Comment: @Johannes: His claim in his question is that Intel specifies load/store ordering. Now, I haven't checked it myself, but if he is right then the effects he wants can be guaranteed without explicit CPU barriers, on x86 anyway.

Comment: @Zan Lynx: No, Johannes Dahlström is right. The fact that _you_ put the moves in a particular order doesn't mean that they'll end up in that order in your binary. The optimizer is free to swap the instructions, which (on x86) also swaps the actual stores.

Comment: @MSalters: If you place your code in an assembly block, the compiler optimizer WILL NOT REORDER IT. It may reorder the entire block, gcc can do that. But it will not reorder code within the block.

Comment: @Zan Lynx: You continue to claim that there exists a rule against this reordering; please point it out. I cannot show the absence of such a rule.

Comment: @MSalters: You are being ridiculous. The purpose of `asm` blocks would be completely undermined if the compiler could reorder the contents as it pleased. Also, I have never observed such reordering. I believe it rests on you to prove that the compiler or assembler does reorder assembly instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the platform guarantees sequential consistency, you will *always* need some sort of synchronization to prevent *race conditions* when more than one thread accesses the same memory location and at least one of them writes into it. C++0x offers three ways to implement such synchronization:

1. Mutual exclusion - `std::mutex` and related classes
2. Atomic variables - `std::atomic<T>`
3. Explicit memory barriers - `std::atomic_thread_fence`.

The latter two accept a *memory order* parameter permitting extra flexibility (for experts only!) on platforms that do not guarantee sequential consistency, but this is not relevant on x86.

Comment: Sequential guarantees *are* a way to avoid data races. At a low-level we aren't looking to use *mutex* as it is too costly. The question is more how to make use of other memory ordering guarantees in a platform independent fashion.

Comment: `atomic_thread_fence` is the part I'm very unclear of in the standard. The wording seems to imply that the ordering is only guaranteed for `atomic` types, which would be nearly useless.  I'm going to ask a more targeted question about that.